# .exr ExceptionFlags contradict .lastevent

Tags: debugging, exception, windbg, internals

Today I saw a .NET NullReferenceException which IMHO should be a first chance exception since the exception is caught and displayed as a MessageBox.

In WinDbg, it looks like this:

```
0:000> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 000007fe8e5794ba
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000149
Attempt to write to address 0000000000000149
```

I wondered if `ExceptionFlags` contains that information, but the WinDbg help `.hh .exr` does not explain the output.

Reading [MSDN for EXCEPTION_RECORD structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I found out

- This member can be either zero, indicating a continuable exception
- or EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE indicating a noncontinuable exception

and [also on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259964%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) that EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE has a value of 1.

So far, this matches my expectations, I have a first chance exception.

But then I did

```
0:000> .lastevent
Last event: 12c0.b2c: Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
```

Why does `.lastevent` think the information is not present? Which command is more reliable?

Comment: I wonder if there are any other exception records for the same thread or other threads. IIRC, they are on the stack. In x86 you could search the stack for 0x1003f but not sure about x64. Maybe look at all the thread stacks to see if any others have raised an exception.